# Access HTML Code of another document of same server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was working on reading a source of a html page (on the same site **not cross domain**) and use the div content to be shown on another page.

I want to access the HTML content of `source.html` without actually *loading* the file.

It is important for me to use HTML DOM only. I don't prefer to load the *complete html source* on a `String` var and parse it using REGEX or XML.

One of the approaches is to use frames and put the source html file on a frame and setting the src

```
parent.window.document.getElementById('sourceFrame').src = "htmlfiles/source.html";
```

this will load the source on a frame, allow to collect the div content by using

```
divHTML = parent.window.frames["sourceFrame"].document.getElementById("targetClassname").innerHTML
```

and show it on the target page using

```
document.getElementById("targetClassname").innerHTML = divHTML
```

This works fine but, it will load/show the HTML file. 0% width frame cannot be a solution as it WILL load the html document, its not visible that's it.

So, its about accessing the HTML content of `source.html` without actually *loading* the file, Any thoughts?

Comment: Just retrieve it via ajax? `$.get("source.html", function(html) { ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an ajax request to get it, and then do with it what you want

```
$.ajax("htmlfiles/source.html", {
  success: function(sourceFile){
    // do something with the html file (sourceFile)
  }
});
```

Comment: & @RGraham: I see that the parameter sourceFile in `$.ajax("htmlfiles/source.html", {
  success: function(sourceFile){
    // do something with the html file (sourceFile)
  }
});` returns HTML String. How can i use that to find info like `sourceFile.document.getElementsByClassName("JD")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: As you're using jQuery: `$(sourceFile).find(".JD").first().html();` Non-jQuery can use `document.createElement` to create the DOM element without adding it to the page, then use normal DOM functions (like `getElementsByClassName`)